# Merge the all elements of multiple columns into one column in series while keeping NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

Context: I have 5 years of weight data. The first column is the date (month and day), the succeeding columns are the years with corresponding weight for each day of the month. I want to have a full plot of all of my data among other things and so I want to combine all into just two columns. First column is the dates from 2018 to 2022, then the second column is the corresponding weight to each date. I have managed the date part, but can't combine the weight data. In essence, I want to turn ...

```
   0    1
0  1  4.0
1  2  NaN
2  3  6.0
```

Into ...

```
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  NaN
5  6.0
```

`pd.concat` only puts the year columns next to each other. `.join`, `.merge`, `melt`, `stack`. `agg` don't work either. How do I do this?

sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'2018': [1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'2019': [4, np.NaN, 6]})

merged_df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1, ignore_index=True, levels = 0)
print(merged_df)
```

P.S. I particularly don't want to input any index names (like `id_vars="2018"`) because I want this process to be automated as the years go by with more data.

concat, merge, melt, join, stack, agg. i want to combine all column data into just one series

Comment: Are you working on two dataframes, or just one? Your initial example is a single dataframe

Comment: What's your starting point? The two dictionaries you make the dataframes from? A csv file? A SQL Query?

Comment: it's just one dataframe loaded from a CSV file. in the example provided there are 2 dataframes to show that pd.concat doesn't really do what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `np.ravel(merged_df,order='F')` will do the job for you.

If you want it in the form of a dataframe then `pd.DataFrame(np.ravel(merged_df,order='F'))`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not fully clear what's your *I/O* but based on your first example, you can use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) like this :

```
pd.concat([df["0"], df["1"].rename("0")], ignore_index=True)
```

Output :

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    NaN
5    6.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```